# Generate java classes from xsd in myeclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxb, myeclipse

Is there any jaxb plugin for myeclipse that will generate java classes by giving the xsd? I have tried jars and includes in plugins folder of myeclipse but with no use.

Answer (score 0):

In normal Eclipse you can right click the .xsd file and then select `Generate > JAXB Classes`. You must also make sure JAXB is installed, otherwise first install that plugin.

If you want classes to be generated when ever the .xsd file changes you might also want to look into one of the JAXB-Maven extensions.